# Apachesolr search result sorting

Tags: solr

I'm trying to change sorting from apache Solr query.

for example bundle type: story, videogallery and category_management are indexed.

I wanted to show all results related to bundle type: category_management on top.
See attached screenshot:
[image]

Please help me to user Solr filter to sort my result.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to apply a boost to any entry that matches your requirement:

```
&bq=bundle:category_management^50
```

The weight - `50` - may have to be adjusted to get the result you want. This is faster than sorting by a function.

This will also still keep relevancy score inside each set of documents, compared to sorting by a function or adding a `priority` field for sorting.

If you want to actually apply a sort on multiple fields instead, you can first [sort by a function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html) that returns `1` for values that match and `0` for values that doesn't. Something like:

```
sort=if(termfreq(bundle,'category_management'),1,0),ds_changed desc
```

Comment: No Luck. I have add "bundle:category_management^50" in "bq" dismax.

Comment: But you have a `sort` condition in your screenshot. If you're asking for the results to be sorted by a field, the results will be sorted by that field.

Comment: I need sort condition. with the extra filter for bundle:category_management

Comment: So what you really want is to first sort those that have `category_management` as their bundle, then sort by `ds_changed` within those two groups?

Comment: Yes. if possible, otherwise I need to alter results from Drupal.

Comment: I've added an example using `if()` and `termfreq`. Test it for your data.

Comment: can not sort on a field which is neither indexed nor has doc values: if(termfreq(bundle,category_management),1,0),ds_changed